# How to choose shared memory interfaces in Linux?

Tags: linux, shared-memory

Linux has two different ways to manage shared memory: `shm_open()/mmap()` and `shmget()/shmat()`.  What are the pros and cons of each?  How do I decide which one to choose for my application?

Comment: possible duplicate of [System V IPC vs POSIX IPC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582968/system-v-ipc-vs-posix-ipc)

Comment: Generally: SysV IPC has a somewhat stupid API, but is more widely available. If you can stick with modern Linux versions, I'd go with POSIX.

Comment: You're right, searching for the names of the functions didn't turn up the right question, which is why I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

I am asking myself the same question, and I don't know the final answer, but I thought I would share my benchmarks.

I have found that out-of-the box, the POSIX `shm_open` framework is faster than the System V `shmget`.

In my benchmark, I write 32 GB of memory from one process and read the same 32 GB of memory and verify it. I use ZeroMQ to pass ownership tokens from the writer to the reader to keep things in sync. The memory block size is actually pretty small, 32KB, but I've found this doesn't seem to be a rate limiting factor, neither does the presence of ZeroMQ make a big difference.

I've found that the net throughput using **POSIX shared memory is about 40% faster than System V shared memory**.  Specifically, the net operation (write + read) operates at a sustained rate of 3.5 GB/s for the POSIX shared memory and 2.5 GB/s for the System V shared memory.

As why this is true, I don't know.  I've also found these benchmarks a bit slippery if you don't pin down process and memory affinities, although this speed difference appears to be present regardless of any combination of CPU binding and memory binding (using `numactl`).