# shared memory proper cleanup in linux C

Tags: c, shared-memory

I am developing a shared memory suite of applications, in C, on Ubuntu 12.04 server.

This is my first attempt at dealing with shared memory, so I am not sure of all the pitfalls.

My suite starts with a daemon that creates a shared memory segment, and a few other apps that use it.

During development, of course, the segment can get created, then the program crash without removing it. I can see it listed using `ipcs -m`.

Normally, this isn't much of an issue, as the next time I start the "controlling" program, it simply reuses the existing segment.

However, from time to time, the size of the segment changes, so the program fails the `shmget()` function.

My question...

Before I create and attach the segment, I would like to first determine if it already exists, then if needed, unattach it, then I think, shmctl(..., ipc_rmd, ...).

Can I have some help to figure the proper sequence of events to do this?

I think I should use `shmctl` to see what's up, (number of attachments, if it exists, etc..) but I don't really know.

It may be there is another app still using the segment, of course that app will have to first be stopped, and any other possible exceptions handled.

I was thinking, in the shared memory segment, I could copy the system clock, and when the app detects the clock of the shared mem differs more then a few seconds, then detach or something.

Thanks, Mark.

Comment: Why did you choose System V IPC instead of POSIX? I find POSIX shared memory easier to use and manage. Besides, you have tons of example on the Net. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582968/system-v-ipc-vs-posix-ipc

Comment: The way I understand the POSIX approach is, any shared mem must come from some child of a parent that created the shared segment (fork, exec, etc...) perhaps I am wrong, at least I haven't figured out how to do the following.  I will be creating some other apps that will use the shared segment totally independent of the creator.