# How to map oracle sga memory into physical files in solaris?

Tags: oracle, solaris

Is there a way by which we could map Oracle SGA memory into physical files in solaris?
We could find these physical files in /dev/shm/ folder in linux environment but they are missing in solaris.

Answer (score 2):

**Is there a way by which we could map Oracle SGA memory into physical files in solaris?**

Not that I'm aware of.

The SGA on Solaris uses Sys V shared memory.  See [System V IPC vs POSIX IPC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582968/system-v-ipc-vs-posix-ipc) for a discussion of the differences between the two.

Solaris provides significant platform-specific performance-enhancing features in its implementation of Sys V shared memory.  For example, Solaris provides "intimate shared memory".  From [the Solaris `shmat` man page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19109-01/tsolaris8/816-1056/6m7gi1i4p/index.html):

> When (*shmflg*&`SHM_SHARE_MMU`) is true, virtual memory resources in
>   addition to shared memory itself are shared among processes that use
>   the same shared memory.

Those performance enhancements are not available using POSIX shared memory, so Sys V shared memory is likely to remain in use on Solaris for a long time.